# Play animation sequentially - Motion Layout

Tags: android, animation, android-motionlayout

So far, I've read all the documentation available about `MotionLayout` [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout) (the official docs), examples available on it, a very complex example [here](https://proandroiddev.com/complex-ui-animations-on-android-featuring-motionlayout-aa82d83b8660) and other examples from many websites. 
What I failed to get so far is how to play/start the animations one by one.

The `KeyPosition` and `KeyAttribute` are possibly the answer but I didn't find any example/documentation explaining how can I utilise them.

This is the `MotionScene` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:duration="500">
    </Transition>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/bottomText"
            />
    </ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/bottomText"
            />
    </ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start1">
        <Constraint
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/arcView"
            />
    </ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end1">
        <Constraint
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".8"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/arcView"
            />
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

This is how I start it: (it doesn't start automatically even with the `autoTransition`)

```
val motionContainer : MotionLayout = findViewById(R.id.motionContainer)
motionContainer.setTransition(R.id.start, R.id.end)
motionContainer.transitionToEnd()
```

The complex example above uses `motionLayout.doOnEnd()` to start the next transition but that is not an available function, nor I found it anywhere in his code. As I checked more, `doOnEnd()` is a function of `Animator()` but no relation of it with `MotionScene`/`MotionLayout` could be found.

I thought by passing next transition it would work as shown below but that didn't help too.

```
val motionContainer : MotionLayout = findViewById(R.id.motionContainer)
motionContainer.setTransition(R.id.start, R.id.end)
motionContainer.transitionToEnd()
motionContainer.setTransition(R.id.start1, R.id.end1)
motionContainer.transitionToEnd()
```

So, **how to play these transitions one by one?**

Comment: I wanted to use my animations the same way, but it looks that MotionLayout which allows to create "super complex animations" doesn't support so obvious use case. Have you in the end figure it out how to do this?

Comment: @prf No, actually I didn't find any answer, even on a similar github issue I found back then, they had said such a thing is not possible. You can't actually control the flow in code, but you can play with the `framePosition` to make the animations play sequentially by themselves as a one whole animation, see the voted answer below for that.

Comment: Yes, I saw that thing regarding KeyFrames, but in my opinion it is not so intuitive. Anyway, I will give it a try. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @prf Actually, it doesn't my purpose either which is why I didn't use it and didn't mark the answer. It is not at all what I want. Also, the complex animation medium article I've shared in the question can be very helpful, try that.

Answer (score 2):

You can realize it by using a **KeyFrameSet**. Assuming that you want to first animate bottomText and then arcView, with equal durations, it should be something like this:

```
<KeyFrameSet>
        <KeyPosition
            app:framePosition="50"
            app:motionTarget="@id/bottomText"
            app:keyPositionType="pathRelative"
            app:percentX="1"/>

        <KeyPosition
            app:framePosition="50"
            app:motionTarget="@id/arcView"
            app:keyPositionType="pathRelative"
            app:percentX="0"/>
    </KeyFrameSet>
```

This means, I want the first view (bottomText) to complete its path at the half of the total animation duration. And I want the second view (arcView) to stay at the same position until the half of the total animation duration, in other words, until the first view completes animating.

If you want one of them to be animated faster or slower, play with the framePosition attribute.

For more explanation on these attributes, [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/ref/keyposition) is the official doc.

Answer (score 2):

You can add

> `motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd"`

this code after run `trans2` will auto run `trans3`,  set `motion:constraintSetEnd` first transition to `motion:constraintSetEnd` at second transition

setForm -> setQuiz -> setQuizReady

```xml
    <Transition

        android:id="@+id/trans2"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/setQuiz"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/setForm"
        motion:duration="5000"
        motion:pathMotionArc="none">
        <KeyFrameSet>
        </KeyFrameSet>

    </Transition>
    <Transition
        motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd"
        android:id="@+id/trans3"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/setQuizReady"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/setQuiz"
        motion:duration="5000"
        motion:pathMotionArc="none">
        <KeyFrameSet>
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>
```